# How to make clickable anchor text in django app?

Tags: python, django

I am learning django by making a simple app. I have this text that I want to be clickable when the page is loaded.

```
single_text = '<a href="https://my-link.dot-com">Cows  </a> lose their jobs as milk prices drop'
```

As of now, the whole thing is being displayed and I want only the word "cow" to show with the link attached while the rest of the sentence is not part of the anchor text. How do I go about it? Or maybe point me in the right direction as far as what I should search for in the docs?

Comment: I think you should go through this official tutorial. It is a great place to start.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: @das  maybe i should clarify, Its actually a live blog app that I am extending. I've already gone thru the thing and sort of understood it but now i want clickable text in a post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap everything with a div tag.
Also you might want to use `{{single_text|safe}}` in your template if you return an HttpResponse from your view.

Comment: this works. At first i didn't know what you were talking about but after a little googling, everything became crystal clear

Answer (score 0):

You can sent url from `views.py` if the URL are dynamic. so it should be `url = "https://my-link.dot-com" #The url should be as a Dictionary` then you can use the variable in Django Templates as a  `<a href="{{url}}">Cows lose their jobs as milk prices drop </a>`

Comment: Hi. This actually makes sense but I have made a slight correction to my question. I only need part of the sentence to be the anchor text, not the whole thing. As is the case with blog posts. Thanks